# Alter table with same name in multiple schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table with same name (name-xxx) in 100 different schema in same mysql server.
I want to alter all table named xxx by using a single script (without hard coding
the schema name in the script)

Comment: With the information given, one option is to use [13.6.6 Cursors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html) with [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
DECLARE @alterQ NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(45)

DECLARE tables_curs CURSOR FOR
  SELECT t.table_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
   WHERE t.table_name = 'xxx'
     AND t.table_catalog = 'db_name'

OPEN tables_curs 
FETCH tables_curs INTO @table_name

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN 

  SET @table_name  = N'ALTER TABLE @table_name ...'
  EXEC sp_executesql @alterQ

END

CLOSE tables_curs 
DEALLOCATE tables_curs
```